# Un inner join multiplica mis resultados

Tags: sql, sql-server

He estado intentando arreglar este error. El siguiente SQL multiplica mis resultados de las columnas percepciones y deducciones:

```
SELECT S.Nombre_sucursal as Nombre_sucursal, CONCAT(E.Nombre,' ',E.Apellido_paterno,'',E.Apellido_materno) as Nombre_completo,
SUM(NP.Monto) as Percepciones,SUM(ND.Monto) as deducciones,E.Salario_diario*15 as Salario_quincenal

FROM Nominas N
INNER JOIN Empleados E ON E.Id_empleado = N.Id_empleado_fk
INNER JOIN Sucursales S ON S.Id_sucursal = E.Id_sucursal_fk
INNER JOIN Nomina_percepciones NP ON NP.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina
INNER JOIN Nomina_deducciones ND ON ND.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina
group by S.Nombre_sucursal, E.Nombre, E.Apellido_paterno, E.Apellido_materno,NP.Monto,E.Salario_diario
```

Si elimino cualquiera de los inner joins de Nomina_percepciones o Nomina_deducciones, me arroja los resultados correctos.

```
Ejemplo:
SELECT S.Nombre_sucursal as Nombre_sucursal, CONCAT(E.Nombre,' ',E.Apellido_paterno,'',E.Apellido_materno) as Nombre_completo,
SUM(NP.Monto) as Percepciones,E.Salario_diario*15 as Salario_quincenal

FROM Nominas N
INNER JOIN Empleados E ON E.Id_empleado = N.Id_empleado_fk
INNER JOIN Sucursales S ON S.Id_sucursal = E.Id_sucursal_fk
INNER JOIN Nomina_percepciones NP ON NP.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina
group by S.Nombre_sucursal, E.Nombre, E.Apellido_paterno, E.Apellido_materno,E.Salario_diario
```

En este caso el resultado de las percepciones seria correcto.
Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido @DiegoRamos a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Seria productivo si muestras los dos resultados. Redacta la information si es necesario.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos probar tu query y ver esos duplicados montando un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Por centrar la pregunta: si ya tienes los resultados correctos, ¿qué nos estás preguntando exactamente? Si te fijas en la redacción de tu pregunta, sólo haces afirmaciones... :) Lo que llamas error, ¿es un error o un resultado que no esperas? Si es un error, añádelo a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás realizando un producto cartesiano ya que los detalles de ambas tablas no se pueden relacionar. La mejor opción es realizar la suma de forma previa para ambas tablas. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT S.Nombre_sucursal as Nombre_sucursal, 
        CONCAT(E.Nombre,' ',E.Apellido_paterno,'',E.Apellido_materno) as Nombre_completo,
        NP.Monto as Percepciones,
        ND.Monto as deducciones,
        E.Salario_diario*15 as Salario_quincenal
FROM Nominas N
INNER JOIN Empleados E ON E.Id_empleado = N.Id_empleado_fk
INNER JOIN Sucursales S ON S.Id_sucursal = E.Id_sucursal_fk
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_Nomina, SUM(Monto) AS Monto FROM Nomina_percepciones GROUP BY Id_Nomina) NP ON NP.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_Nomina, SUM(Monto) AS Monto FROM Nomina_deducciones GROUP BY Id_Nomina) ND ON ND.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina;
```

En lo personal, creo que usando CTEs puedes tener un código más organizado para que quede de la siguiente forma.

```
WITH Suma_Nomina_Percepciones AS(
    SELECT ID_Nomina, 
            SUM(Monto) AS Monto 
    FROM Nomina_percepciones
    GROUP BY Id_Nomina
),
Suma_Nomina_Deducciones AS(
    SELECT ID_Nomina, 
            SUM(Monto) AS Monto 
    FROM Nomina_deducciones
    GROUP BY Id_Nomina
)
SELECT S.Nombre_sucursal as Nombre_sucursal, 
        CONCAT(E.Nombre,' ',E.Apellido_paterno,'',E.Apellido_materno) as Nombre_completo,
        NP.Monto as Percepciones,
        ND.Monto as deducciones,
        E.Salario_diario*15 as Salario_quincenal
FROM Nominas N
INNER JOIN Empleados E ON E.Id_empleado = N.Id_empleado_fk
INNER JOIN Sucursales S ON S.Id_sucursal = E.Id_sucursal_fk
INNER JOIN Suma_Nomina_Percepciones NP ON NP.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina
INNER JOIN Suma_Nomina_Deducciones ND ON ND.Id_nomina_fk = N.Id_nomina;
```

Recuerda que siempre es importante mantener un código legible para evitar gastar tiempo al momento de darle mantenimiento.